# Error during installation of nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

```
$ yo --version && bower --version && grunt --version
```

When i run this command I got the error shown below :

```
1.6.0
1.7.7
grunt-cli v0.1.13
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './schema/safe'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\node_modules\grunt\node_modules\js-yaml\lib\js-yaml\loader.js:8:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you split it in 3 commands? Like this: `yo --version` then `bower --version` then `grunt --version`?

Comment: what does this has to do with angularjs..?